# Google Analytics IOS v2(beta) crash under ARC

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, google-analytics

I get the following crash from Google Analytics v2.0 beta 3:
It's started by:

```
 __45-[GAIDispatcher queueDispatch:url:timestamp:]_block_invoke_0 + 119 at GAIDispatcher.m:633
```

Followed by:

```
 -[GAIDispatcher persistAndDispatch:url:timestamp:] + 427 at GAIDispatcher.m:525
```

The error is:

```
** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb68c690
```

My setup is as follows:
I have an app that uses ARC (the limited one.. from ios 4.3)
My app supports a minimum SDK of 4.3, developed under SDK 6.0.
The crash appears only on the simulator (works fine on device) and it's a EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

All I have in my code is this, in applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = NO;
// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 5;
// Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
// Create tracker instance.
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:UA_NUMBER];


 [tracker trackEventWithCategory:@"TestV1"
                      withAction:@"ActionV1"
                       withLabel:@"LabelV1"
                       withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?
Your help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

P.S.: This is the Zombie detected when running with the Zombies tool.

```
#   Address Category    Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp   Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   0xd18fe30   __NSDictionaryM Malloc  1   00:20.889.002   32  PostcodeGazette -[GAIDispatcher queueDispatch:url:]
1   0xd18fe30   __NSDictionaryM Autorelease     00:20.889.015   0   PostcodeGazette -[GAIDispatcher queueDispatch:url:]
2   0xd18fe30   __NSDictionaryM Release 0   00:24.832.529   0   UIKit   _UIApplicationHandleEvent
3   0xd18fe30   __NSDictionaryM Zombie  -1  00:25.067.003   0   PostcodeGazette -[GAIDispatcher persistAndDispatch:url:timestamp:]
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: What I did was to disable it for simulator and leave it enabled only when running on device.

Comment: Similar issue with v 3.0.2 and cant figure out the reason :
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.02 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:414): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        ...
    };
    timestamp = "2014-01-08 19:55:05 +0000";
}

 malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1048576) failed (error code=3)
    *** error: can't allocate region
    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
    ChevronRetail(7811,0x3bc01a8) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1048576) failed (error code=3)
    *** error: can't allocate region
    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug